# "BETWEEN a AND b" is much slower than "x > a AND x < b"

Tags: performance, sqlite, between

Running on an ARM processor with linux OS, I'm using SQLite, and I have a table with some columns. the first is ID and the second is Time Stamp and the rest are data values.
The column Time Stamp is indexed.

When I want to read some rows from the table, I use:

```
 select * from Table1 where (Time_Stamp_Start between %d and %d)
```

The query takes around 13 seconds to fetch the results.

When I use the query:

```
 select * from Table1 where (Time_Stamp_Start > %d and Time_Stamp_Start < %d)
```

it takes around 1 second.

So, What is the difference between the two queries? Doesn't SQLite engine parse this query in the same way?

Comment: It should have the same performance (as in, index use) - see [BETWEEN optimization](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html) - but no, it's strictly not parsed the same way. (Note that `x BETWEEN a AND B` is semantically like `x >= a AND x <= b`, so the two queries shown are not guaranteed to produce equivalent output - could there just be *that many* more results included with an inclusive test?)

Comment: Are you using the same values? Is the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) the same? Is it possible that the data is cached when you are executing the second query?